# Adding data while parsing into next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am doing an app, where it takes name and phone number in first activity.
it should save those values and parse to next activity and vice versa.

Eg:

> In Actvity one i kept name1 & age1 --> Save and in the same activity
>   again inserted name2 & age2--> Save

And when i click display it should display both the values saved in another activity.

Here I mentioned 2 cases, but it may vary as 10 or 20 or N.

Kindly, provide on which way we can make it?

Comment: So, you want we to explain you how to pass data between activities through intent extras or how to make a static class to store your data?

Comment: Could you give us some code please? So far, from what you briefly explained It would be `Ìntent newActivity = new Intent(...);... newActivity.putSerializable(yourData);... startActivity(newActivity);`. But IDK is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to pass data between activities then you can use below
>   cases :

**Case : 1**

You can pass data between activites through **Intent**.

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("variable_key","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("variable_key");
}
```

This is for passing data between activities.

**Case : 2**

You can make class of **Static and Public Arraylist's Getter and Setter**.

Example :

```
Class GetterArrayList{

private static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> arrayList;

public static init(){
    if(arrayList== null)
        arrayList= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
}

public static ArrayList<String> getStringList(String key){
    return arrayList.get(key);
}

public static void putStringList(ArrayList<String> value, String key){
    arrayList.put(key, value);
}
}
```

Now initialize your ArrayList class:

```
GetterArrayList.init();
```

Now you can add value in arraylist like below :

```
ArrayList<String> listNew = new ArrayList<String>();
listNew .add("Your data");
GetterArrayList.putStringList(listNew , "newList");
```

And you can get your arraylist in another class by key.

```
for(String s:GetterArrayList.getStringList("newList")){

Log.d("My list",s);

}
```

**Case : 3**

You can use **Shared preferences** for passing data between activities .

This [link](http://codetheory.in/android-application-data-storage-sharedpreferences/) will help you for shared preferences.

But Here is some trailor.

This is how you can set data

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("string_preference", "some_string");
    prefEditor.putInt("int_preference", 18);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

And this is how you can get the data :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 

  String string_preference= prefs.getString("string_preference", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int int_preference= prefs.getInt("int_preference", 0); //0 is the default value.
```

**Case : 4**

If you want to pass multiple data then you can use **local storage like SQLite Database**.

Here is the [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwiA2Kyeg-PIAhWCLaYKHYxTBNM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidbegin.com%2Ftutorial%2Fandroid-sqlite-database-tutorial%2F&usg=AFQjCNE2Bf7hivh6ROuVomvkg2OJUUxUdg&sig2=soQQ3_-_Ysp8H11n577vDQ&bvm=bv.106130839,d.dGY) for your reference .

Or

How to save data on the device, whether it's temporary files, downloaded app assets, user media, structured data, or something else. You can see more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html#3).**(See Saving data section)**

Save them to a [SQlite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database.

Comment: Thanks for your cases,, could you please link me to the page of case 2. I want to implement by using case 2 method.

Comment: @user3324135 : There no need of any link. I have already provided example to you.